# How to get multiple values from jquery hash

Tags: javascript, url, fragment-identifier

How can i get multiple values in a jquery hash?

Example:

http://mysite.com/#l:value&v:id1212 same as but without page refresh http://mysite.com/?l=value&v=id1212

I thought something like:

```
var hash = location.hash.replace(/^.*?#/, '');

var lVal = (/^l:/.test( hash ));
var vVal = (/^v:/.test( hash ));
```

but how can i fix that var lVal only reads untill the & sign?
Am i on the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your string by `&` sign and then retrieve values:

```
var hash = location.hash.replace(/^.*?#/, '');
var pairs = hash.split('&');
var lVal = pairs[0].split(':')[1];
var vVal = pairs[1].split(':')[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you might be looking for something like [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/) to help you ease the pain. Also [URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/) has a fragment-abuse plugin for [data fragments](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/docs.html#fragment-abuse-query). Otherwise try something like

```
var data = {};
var tokens = location.hash.substring(1).split('&');
for (var i=0, l=tokens.length; i < l; i++) {
  var token = tokens[i].split(':');
  // maybe token[1] is escaped or something?!
  data[token[0]] = token[1];
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the method of Engineer is exactly what i was looking for.